# How to create Structure & Template programmatically in Liferay 6

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-velocity

I need to create the Structure and Template progrmatically through java code.I used following code snippets.

**Structure:**

```
public void createStructure(String userName,long userId){
        log_.info("Inside create structure ");
        long structureId=115203;
        DDMStructure ddmStructure=DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.createDDMStructure(structureId);
        ddmStructure.setName("MigrationStructure");
        ddmStructure.setDescription("This Structure created programatically");
        ddmStructure.setUserId(userId);
        ddmStructure.setUserName(userName);
        File fXmlFile = new File("D:/FilesDataMigration/structure.xml");        
        try {           
            Document document = SAXReaderUtil.read(fXmlFile);
            ddmStructure.setDocument(document);
            DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.addDDMStructure(ddmStructure);
        }catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        log_.info("Inside create structure done");
    }
```

**Template:**

```
public void createTemplate(String userName,long userId){
        log_.info("Inside create template ");
        long templateId=12504;
        DDMTemplate ddmTemplate=DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil.createDDMTemplate(templateId);
        ddmTemplate.setName("MigrationTemplate");
        ddmTemplate.setDescription("This Template created programatically");
        ddmTemplate.setUserId(userId);
        ddmTemplate.setUserName(userName);

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/FilesDataMigration/template.txt"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String script = sb.toString();
            ddmTemplate.setScript(script);
            DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil.addDDMTemplate(ddmTemplate);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log_.info("Inside create template done");
    }
```

The above snippets are executing properly with out any exceptions But unable to see in the content section of Control Panel.Suggest me if anything wrong

Comment: First of all, what sort of structures or templates do you want to create?

Comment: You are not setting all the required properties, like `classNameId`, `language` etc

Comment: Also, better to use `DDMStructure ddmStructure = DDMStructureUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());` and 
`DDMTemplate ddmTemplate = DDMTemplateUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());` in place of hard-coded ids.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Thanks a lot it works for me.But i have doubt how to set classNameId and ClassName without hard coding like as you suggested for strcture id.

Comment: ddmStructure.setClassName("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle");ddmStructure.setClassNameId(10109); This is not the correct way of doing.Please can you suggest me

Comment: You can get `ClassName` object using `ClassName className = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassName(""com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle"");`, then use `className.getClassNameId()` for setting `classNameId` for structure / template.

Comment: Also, better to use `DDMStructureUtil.update(ddmStructure);` instead of `DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.addDDMStructure(ddmStructure);` when you are finished setting required properties. Same goes for `DDMTemplate` as well.

Comment: Don't forget to associate your structure to a site: `ddmStructure.setGroupId(groupId);`

Comment: and also the company (instance id): `ddmStructure.setCompanyId(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code:

1. You are not setting all the required properties, like `groupId, companyId, classNameId, structureKey, dates` etc.
2. There isn't any `setName` and `setDescription` method for `DDMStructure` or `DDMTemplate` accepting `String` argument (`Liferay 6.2 GA2`). Instead, there are only `setNameMap` and `setDescriptionMap` methods for both accepting `Map<Locale, String>`.
3. Use dynamic ids (`structureId` and `templateId`) in place of hard-coded ids, as following:
   `DDMStructure ddmStructure = DDMStructureUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());`and
   `DDMTemplate ddmTemplate = DDMTemplateUtil.create(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());`
4. For `classNameId`, you can get it using it's value, like:
   `ClassName className = ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassName("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.Journ‌​alArticle");
   long classNameId = className.getClassNameId();`
5. Also, better to use `update` over populated object in place of adding:
   `DDMStructureUtil.update(ddmStructure);`
   and
   `DDMTemplateUtil.update(ddmTemplate);`

Additionally, if you have access to the `ThemeDisplay` object, you can get `groupId, companyId, userId, userFullName` from it. Also, set `new Date()` for `createDate` and `modifiedDate` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and patience.I set some of the things but i didn't update here.You explained very well here and understood very clearly and learnt some of the best practices.

Comment: I able to set all the things but what about structure key as it is expecting Stirng.How to avoid hard coding of this one.

Comment: Well, I am not pretty much sure about that, but, looking at the records for web content structures in database, I have observed that `structureKey` is always `-1` of `structureId`. Therefore you can set it like `String structureKey = Long.toString(ddmStructure.getStrucutureId() - 1);`

Comment: ok.Thank You.But i didn't see in the DB as you said.If i create directly without setting StructureKey,It is getting populated automatically in DB

Comment: That is fine, this is what I have observed in my database, when creating structures from control panel.